What are best practices for updating ca certs on embedded devices that may be unpowered for months at a time?
If we want to deliver an embedded device with networking, it needs to have a CA certificate store.
However, the device may sit on the shelf for months, and even in the customer's hands it may go unused (and unpowered) for long periods of time.
Are there any recommendations for how to handle CA Cert stores that may expire while there is no networking available?  I'm concerned about being unable to use TLS to fetch new CAs due to expiration.
It doesn't feel right to fall back to insecure methods after the whole store has expired.  Is this even a real concern?  I have no sense for how long root certs last.

"I have no sense for how long root certs last."  Depends on the CA.  It's not uncommon to have a CA cert good for 20 years, however if you examine your machine you'll likely find some that are due to expire as soon as next year.  This is why really outdated machines can still visit some pages and not others (although SSL/TLS changes over time too)

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12353/how-long-shall-a-certificate-be-valid, https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177834/is-the-offline-root-ca-obsolete, and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/94982/what-is-cross-signing-of-root-certificates-and-how-does-it-help-at-time-of-root

This isn't specific to updating CA certificates but applies to any firmware updates on your device: firmware updates should be signed by a key/certificate which is under your own control, i.e. you should not rely solely on transport security like TLS for this. And this signature should be verified on the device before installing the firmware update.
If the firmware update is signed with a key controlled by you and trusted on the device, then this update could be safely transported even using an insecure transport protocol like plain HTTP. This way you could not only update CA certificates in a secure way but any other software on the device.
Apart from that public root CA are usually very long lived, so being offline for a year should not be a problem - the (public) root CA on the device will very likely be still valid after a year. It might be a problem for any software vulnerabilities found and fixed while the device was offline though. So first you should do when getting online is to install any new firmware fixing these vulnerabilities anyway - and when doing this you might as well include CA updates in the firmware.
